# Does 'pnet' in a user's Id have any special meaning?

Tags: apex, trigger, user-record

I am working on an app and in one of the triggers there is this exotic bird:

```
if( UserInfo.getUserId().indexOf('pnet') != -1 ) {
    return;
}
```

Looks terribly hard coded or is there a general rule that users with a certain role / profile / superpowers have this sequence in their Id's?

Comment: It appears to have to do something with Salesforce-to-Salesforce, as you can find `pnet` referenced but unexplained [in this documentation](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/business_network_tips.htm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code couldn't be correct. The [Tips for Using Salesforce to Salesforce](http://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/business_network_tips.htm) document that Phil R linked in the original question comments refers to `pnet` being embedded in the alias, while this code checks the `User.Id` field for those characters, which has an incredibly low probability of appearing.

Either it's meant to work in a single organization where a user happens to have some combination of `pnet`, which would be sensitive to the exact organization this code was written in, or they meant to try and check `User.Alias` so they could detect Salesforce to Salesforce connection updates, which is the more likely scenario. I'd consider changing the code to:

```
User currentUser = [select id, alias from user where id = :userinfo.getuserid()];
if(currentUser.Id.indexOf('pnet') != -1 || currentUser.Alias.indexOf('pnet') != -1) {
```

This supports the current (possibly incorrect) logic as well as what the author probably meant to begin with-- detecting Salesforce to Salesforce connections.

Given that the documentation suggests that the user alias will contain `pnet`, it's safe to assume that a Salesforce to Salesforce user-- a proxy user created by the system to represent updates from the connected system-- will always contains this string in its alias.